# Non homogenous differential equation based on a fraction

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I am new to Differential Equations (first week), and I am stuck with the following question:

> Let $y(x)$ be a solution of the initial value problem
>   $$\begin{cases}y'=\frac{x-y-1}{x-y-2}\\ y(0)=2\end{cases}$$
>   Then what is $y(6)$?
>
> Options: a. $-10$, b. $0$, c. $2$, d. $4$, e. $6$, f. $8$.

So far, I have simply integrated $\frac{x-y-1}{x-y-2}$ based on x, and then entered $y(0)=2$ to find $C$. I realize there must be a more elegant trick, but at the same time do not understand why my answer is wrong (it must be wrong, because it does not figure amongst the answers given).

Thank you very much!

Comment: be careful! $y$ is a function of $x$, so integrating the whole expression with respect to $x$ seems fishy.

Have you learned about substitution of variables? For example, $z = 2y - x$ or anything like that?

Comment: I've typed up a fairly complete set of notes for solving these kinds of problems. Yours is Case 2, where the two lines are parallel and non-intersecting. You can see the notes here: https://mathhelpboards.com/math-notes-49/solving-rational-odes-form-ax-c-dx-ex-fy-g-dy-0-a-26350.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative method where we DO NOT find the solution of the Cauchy problem.

The ODE can be written as
$$(x-y-1)+(-x+y+2)y'=0.$$
Now consider the function (the so-called [first integral](https://www.math24.net/first-integrals/)),
$$F(x,y)=\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{2}-xy-x+2y$$
and note that if $y(x)$ is a solution then $x\to F(x,y(x))$ is a constant function:
$$\frac{d(F(x,y(x)))}{dx}=F_x(x,y(x))+F_y(x,y(x)) y'(x)=0.$$

Thus, if $y(0)=2$ then  $F(x,y(x))=F(0,2)=6$ and for $x=6$ we get
$$\frac{36}{2}+\frac{y^2}{2}-6y-6+2y=2.$$
yields that $y=6$ or $y=2$.

Since the denominator $x-y-2$ is not zero along a solution and it is negative at the initial point $(0,2)$,  then it should be negative also at $(6,y(6))$ which implies that $y(6)=6$ (and the value $y=2$ has to be excluded).

Comment: A very good answer, thank you! I just do not really understand the last paragraph (my fault, of course: I just started studying this). Is there any way you could expand a tiny bit on why I should reject y=2)? Thanks!

Comment: Along a solution the derivative $y'(x)$ should be defined and the denominator has to be $\not=0$. If at the beginning it is negative and at another point it is postive, it should be zero at an intermediate point.

Comment: Ah, of course… OK, got it!

Comment: Can you flesh out how you arrived at $F?$

Comment: It is the so-called fist integral: https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/First_integral

Comment: I was getting more at how you actually calculate it. What are the steps to produce $F,$ given the original DE? The link you gave doesn't really say how you do that. I'm asking because from a student's perspective, the $F$ here is kind of like the $L$ in the definition of a limit - no one tells you how to actually obtain it. You know what to do with it once you do!

Comment: Maybe a better reference could be https://www.math24.net/first-integrals/
The idea is to find a scalar function which is invariant along the solutions (with worked examples). It is not always possible to find such function, but in this case, finding $F$ was quite easy. Integrate $(x-y-1)$ with respect to x and then take the derivative with respect to $y$ in order to find $(-x+y+2)$.

Comment: A better link, but all the Lie derivative stuff is going to be very confusing to a sophomore-level student studying ODEs (my guess as to where this question originated). It's completely unnecessary machinery for this level of problem.

Comment: The general theory of first-integrals is not simple and I can not find a better reference (any suggestions are welcome). However,  I think that for this special case, it easy to verify that $F$ has the invariance property and it is interesting to see how this property could be useful to solve the problem without solving the ODE.

Comment: I can't find a better link, either. The one you have has at least some info on finding $F,$ so I can upvote this answer, now.

Answer (score 3):

Let $$v(x)=x-y(x)$$ then

$$-\frac{dv(x)}{dx}+1=\frac{v(x)-1}{v(x)+2}$$ so we get
$$\int\frac{dv(x)}{dx}(v(x)-2)dx=-\int dx$$

Answer (score 0):

An equation of the form $M(x,y)\,dx+N(x,y)\,dy=0$ is exact if 
$$\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}.$$
Then solution is given by $\int M\,dx +\int N\,dy=c$ where the repeating terms in $\int N\,dy$ are avoided.

Comment: Perhaps it would be good to note that the DE can be written $(x-y-2)\,dy+(y-x+1)\,dx=0.$